# Can't embed Google Chart Service in a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In a Google Spreadhseet I have code.gs:

```
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setWidth(900)
      .setHeight(700);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}
```

And index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>

try{
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["calendar"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
dataTable.addRows([
[ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032 ],
[ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024 ],
[ new Date(2012, 3, 15), 38024 ],
[ new Date(2012, 3, 16), 38108 ],
[ new Date(2012, 3, 17), 38229 ],
// Many rows omitted for brevity.
[ new Date(2013, 9, 4), 38177 ],
[ new Date(2013, 9, 5), 38705 ],
[ new Date(2013, 9, 12), 38210 ],
[ new Date(2013, 9, 13), 38029 ],
[ new Date(2013, 9, 19), 38823 ],
[ new Date(2013, 9, 23), 38345 ],
[ new Date(2013, 9, 24), 38436 ],
[ new Date(2013, 9, 30), 38447 ]
]);

var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

var options = {
title: "Red Sox Attendance",
height: 350,
};

chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
} catch(e){
alert(e);
}
</script>


<div id="calendar_basic" style="width: 1000px; height: 350px;"></div>
```

I want to display the chart in a dialog box using the example code from: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar

But this is returning an empty dialog. No errors are thrown.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [very recently](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/speeding-up-htmlservice.html) you have been able to use the Visualisation service in HTMLService created dialog:

An exciting new development in the HTMLService is the addition of the [iFrame sandbox mode which removes a lot of the Caja restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode), one of them being that you can use the Visualisation Service. You just need to add:

```
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
```

to your HTMLService call.

So using this in code.gs (I've added a menu item for the dialog):

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('Show Dialog')
    .addItem('Show dialog...', 'showDialog')
    .addToUi()
}

function showDialog() {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(900)
      .setHeight(700);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}
```

and this in index.html (note you need to bring your Doctype, html, body and back in as it's raw HTML again, not Cajaised):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<div id="calendar_basic" style="width: 1000px; height: 350px;"></div>

<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script>

  try{
    google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["calendar"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
      dataTable.addRows([
      [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032 ],
      [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024 ],
      [ new Date(2012, 3, 15), 38024 ],
      [ new Date(2012, 3, 16), 38108 ],
      [ new Date(2012, 3, 17), 38229 ],
      // Many rows omitted for brevity.
      [ new Date(2013, 9, 4), 38177 ],
      [ new Date(2013, 9, 5), 38705 ],
      [ new Date(2013, 9, 12), 38210 ],
      [ new Date(2013, 9, 13), 38029 ],
      [ new Date(2013, 9, 19), 38823 ],
      [ new Date(2013, 9, 23), 38345 ],
      [ new Date(2013, 9, 24), 38436 ],
      [ new Date(2013, 9, 30), 38447 ]
      ]);

      var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

      var options = {
      title: "Red Sox Attendance",
      height: 350,
      };

        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
  } catch(e){
    alert(e);
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You'll be able to see your chart in the dialog box ... I'm sorry but that is just too cool!

I've created a [quick demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R5fHW8ZecKCzYWc-Io4FEryicG4jga74NOTOtvaT_P4/edit?usp=sharing) if you wanted to see it action. Make a copy if you want to play with the code.

Comment: Hey, this is really cool, I couldn't understand why Google was prohibiting their own chart library in google spreasheets, but anyway... now the problem is solved, thank you! One thing: I found an issue with the new IFRAME mode, if you have the time to look at it, perhaps you could also help with this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460352/how-to-close-sidebar-with-the-new-iframe-mode-in-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, App Script is not able to add the Google Visualization Library. Since App Script is based on the Caja Compiler (https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/), it is not guaranteed that external JS libraries will properly work.

You can read more details on the following link:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#javascript

Comment: this means I can build a chart from a webpage like: http://jsfiddle.net/rn183xLx/ but not from a dialog in a Spreadsheet. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. As you are probably aware, Google Spreadsheet has its own charts for data visualization. But the JS code you can run dynamically is a bit constrained.