# How to close sidebar with the new IFRAME mode in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a sidebar in a spreadsheet. Due to the introduction of the new `IFRAME` mode,  I'm now initialising the sidebar with:

```
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

It is working fine, except now the following function doesn't close the sidebar after successfully running myFunction as per below:

```
 google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
    .myFunction(myVar);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!﻿

Comment: It could be worth listing this on the issue tracker [1] if you can reliably reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

you need a `()` after `close`.
`google.script.host.close()`